# Merge custom listview and tab

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, android-listview

IconTextTabsActivity.java

```
public class IconTextTabsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private int[] tabIcons = {
        R.drawable.ic_tab_favourite,
        R.drawable.ic_tab_call,
        R.drawable.ic_tab_contacts
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_icon_text_tabs);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    setupTabIcons();
}

private void setupTabIcons() {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFrag(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
    adapter.addFrag(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}


class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
}
```

OneFragment.java

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment  implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener{



private static final String TAG = PatientList.class.getSimpleName();
// initially offset will be 0, later will be updated while parsing the json
private int offSet = 0;

// Movies json url
private static final String url = "http://192.168.0.102/test/apps.php";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<Patient> patientList = new ArrayList<Patient>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter listadapter;

private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

public OneFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.patientlist_listview, container, false);

    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);

    listadapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, patientList);
    listView.setAdapter(listadapter);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    // changing action bar color
    // getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
    //        new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00BBD3")));

    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

    /**
     * Showing Swipe Refresh animation on activity create
     * As animation won't start on onCreate, post runnable is used
     */
    swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                                    fetchPatients();
                                }
                            }
    );

    listView.setAdapter(listadapter);

    // Click event for single list row
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(IconTextTabsActivity.this, "row " + position + " was pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    TextView c =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
                    String item = c.getText().toString();
                    Log.d("id", item);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    break;
            }

        }

    });


    return view;

}
/**
 * This method is called when swipe refresh is pulled down
 */
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    fetchPatients();
}
/**
 * Fetching movies json by making http call
 */
private void fetchPatients() {

    // showing refresh animation before making http call
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

    // appending offset to url
    //String url = URL_TOP_250 + offSet;

    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();
                    Log.d("id", "hi") ;
                    // Parsing json
                    // reset the list
                    patientList.clear();
                    listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length();i++) {
                        try {
                            Log.d("id","hi1") ;
                            Log.d("i","i:"+i);

                            Patient patient = new Patient();

                            Log.d("length", "length:" + response.length());
                            JSONObject objid= response.getJSONObject(i);
                            //get id
                            patient.setTitle(objid.getString("id"));

                            //Log.d("i","i:"+i);
                            //obj= response.getJSONObject(i+1);
                            //get image url second item
                            JSONObject objimage= response.getJSONObject(++i);
                            patient.setThumbnailUrl(objimage.getString("image"));
                            //Log.d("i","i:"+i);


                            //patient.setTitle(obj.getString("id"));
                            //patient.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));


                            // Log.d("id",obj.getString("id")) ;
                            //  Log.d("image",obj.getString("image")) ;
                            /*movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                    .doubleValue());
                            movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

                            // Genre is json array
                            JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                            ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                            }
                            movie.setGenre(genre);
                            */

                            // adding movie to movies array
                            if(i%2==1)
                                patientList.add(patient);

                            // updating offset value to highest value
                            //if (i >= offSet)
                            //  offSet = i;

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    // stopping swipe refresh
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hidePDialog();
            Toast.makeText(view.getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // stopping swipe refresh
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    hidePDialog();
}

private void hidePDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }
}

//public PatientList() {
//Required empty public constructor

//}

}
```

Error message

```
Error:(75, 38) error: incompatible types: OneFragment cannot be converted to Context
Error:(72, 45) error: incompatible types: OneFragment cannot be converted to Activity
Error:(223, 32) error: cannot find symbol variable view
Error:(106, 52) error: not an enclosing class: IconTextTabsActivity
```

I want to merge the list view and the tab activity with json.However, it gets the errors in the following 4 lines and I don't know how to solve it.

```
    listadapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, patientList);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    Toast.makeText(IconTextTabsActivity.this, "row " + position + " was pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    public PatientList() {
//Required empty public constructor

}
```

Please give me some helps to deal with this. Thank You.

Comment: Just use `getActivity()` instead of `this` in the Fragment.

Comment: Thx ,it works. May you explain that why can't I use the this and should use getactivity(),please?

Comment: Look at the documentation for all of those methods.  They need either a Context or an Activity.  The Activity class extends Context, so you can use `this` in an Activity for either.  In a Fragment, you need to use `getActivity()` instead of `this`, because a Fragment is not a Context or an Activity.

Answer (score 0):

//Open your Main Activity and extend the class from TabActivity.

```
public class AndroidTabAndListView extends TabActivity
```

//Now open your main.xml under res -> layout folder and create a tabview.

//Create activities for tabs and extend the classes from ListActivity

```
public class Activity extends ListActivity
```

//create xml layouts for the list views.

//Each tab might need an icon so design icons for each tab.

Comment: Thx but I have solved the problem using the above methods so i haven't tried it.

Comment: TabActivity was deprecated in API level 13    http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html